# O que é a linguagem V (Vlang)?

Tags: característica-linguagem, vlang

Me deparei com um código que mais tarde vim a saber se tratar de uma linguagem chamada V (vlang):

```
fn is_prime(x int) bool {
    for i := 2; i <= x / 2; i++ {
        if x % i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

De cara, achei que se tratava de [go](/questions/tagged/go), se não fosse pela declaração de função com `fn` que em Go é `func`:

```
// em Go, usamos "func"
func is_prime(x int) bool {
    for i := 2; i <= x/2; i++ {
        if x%i == 0 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

A sintaxe parece bem similar ao Go e gostaria de saber um pouco mais sobre essa linguagem que aparenta ser recente, pois nem existe a tag [vlang](/questions/tagged/vlang) no SOpt no momento que elaboro essa pergunta.

- O que é a VLang?
- Ela é uma "versão melhorada" do Go?
- Ela surgiu como uma alternativa ao Go?

Comment: Na época em que o projeto estava começando a descrição pareceu muito boa, mas a 1º "luz vermelha" acendeu quando cheguei na descrição do `switch`. Switch tradicionalmente se comporta como `goto`, um dos pontos fortes é você poder fazer um bloco continuar no outro omitindo `break`, mas o autor implementou o `switch` como um mero "`if` travestido" (que infelizmente muita gente ensina errado até em linguagens que tem switch de verdade - `switch` não é substituto de `if`, é um mecanismo diferente e especializado). Pode parecer um mero detalhe no meio das promessas, mas escancara alguns princípios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O resumo é uma linguagem criada por um russo que prometeu um monte de coisas, por alguma razão teve aderência de algumas pessoas, mas ele não consegue entregar tudo o que promete, por vezes mudando sem falar muito sobre.

Ele certamente não é um mané, mas não é uma sumidade das linguagens. Mas a crítica mesmo é sobre a atitude.

Também é verdade que está resolvendo as coisas. Não se pode culpar tanto assim a linguagem não estar nas melhores condições, o desenvolvimento de algo complexo assim leva tempo. Algumas pessoas também exageraram nas críticas, em alguns casos por inveja dele ter conseguido algum sucesso "comercial".

A linguagem tem muitas coisas interessantes, até por vir muito de Go e alguma coisa de Rust. Um dos maiores problemas é o gerenciamento de memória. Está confuso, já mudou algumas vezes e até agora não parece que terá algo bom. Pelo histórico, um dia até ficará bom, mas quebrando algumas promessas e refazendo muita coisa. Um dia ele cai na real de que não é possível fazer o que prometeu sobre isso, mas não vai admitir.

Uma das coisas que eu gosto é ela ser leve e simples. Acho que ele tem mal gosto para escolher alguns detalhes da linguagem, e isso importa, mas também o meu gosto não é o que define algo ser bom ou não. Algumas coisas que ele fez mostram que dá para fazer algo mais simples em alguns mecanismos.

Ela tem aparecido até em [primeiro lugar em alguns testes de performance](https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r21&test=plaintext). Mas só porque o código não tem robustez e possui falhas. É parecido com o que ocorre em um banco de dados que não garante que os dados serão persistidos corretamente em todas as vezes, feito isso será o banco de dados mais rápido do mercado, se você puder perder seus dados.

Não espere que a linguagem se torne popular. Até acho que um dia algumas pessoas usarão de verdade, mas serão bem poucas. Ela não tem nada de muito especial, apesar de alguns detalhes interessantes.

Ela é inspirada em Go, mas não é um Go melhorado, é outra coisa. Ela é uma alternativa, não necessariamente ao Go. Tem várias semânticas bem diferentes, apesar da sintaxe muito parecida. O gerenciamento de memória mesmo é muito diferente por (ainda) não ter um GC.

Eu gosto de acompanhar o que estão fazendo porque gosto do assunto, mas vejo que agora estão em ritmo menor, até porque tem muitos *bugs* para serem corrigidos, alguns graves em nível extremo.

Não se impressione, o que está escrito [no site](https://vlang.io/), mostra ser muito melhor do que realmente é, até onde não é exatamente mentira.

Inclusive lendo lá acabei de ver que adotaram um GC :D Mas pelo que está escrito, tem um bom grau de ingenuidade (vou chamar assim).

Gosta de linguagens? É uma interessante para acompanhar. Só isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Other/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -2):

Muito do que o Maniero falou está correto, tenho acompanhado a 1 ano e pouquinhos o desenvolvimento da linguagem eles estão muito empenhados, e de julho pra cá deu um diminuída no ritmo.

E algo que o Maniero não apontou, pois talvez ele não tenha visto e é até interessante, é a explicação sobre a grande promessa dele que é o autofree, confesso que no início tive muita esperança de ver isso 100%, porém talvez vá ver no mínimo 100% para alguns casos e para outros com vazamento de memória .

[How autofree works #17419](https://github.com/vlang/v/discussions/17419)

Comment: Entendemos seu interesse em contribuir mas leve em consideração o nosso formato. O [pt.so] não é um fórum de discussões ou rede social. Nós somo um site de perguntas e respostas(Q&A), esse espaço deve ser usado apenas para responder a pergunta feita na página de maneira objetiva sendo que as resposta podem citar outras publicações do site mas não devem depender ou serem apêndices de outras respostas.